# Low index/table hit rate on heroku postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I see that index cache hit rate (=80%) and table cache hit rate (=93%) are lower than they should be (>99%).

All frequent queries are using indexes and have execution time ~1ms.

Would removing unused indexes help increasing hit rates? What about adding more indexes?
Or is it time for upgrading the DB? (Adding more RAM especially)

[image]

Comment: Do you have any slow queries? If yes, tune _those_. The cache hit rate is a useless metric in my experience.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. All queries are tuned (execution time <10ms, most of them only take 1ms). But DB is getting bigger. There should probably be a difference if more queries are processed without reading from  hard disc which is slower than RAM.

Comment: So if all queries are fast enough, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Hm. Good question man. From time to time I am seeing slow responses and from New Relic it was not obvious whether the problem is happening due to DB or Dyno. Wasn't sure it table/index cache hit rates could be the reason.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe it is true that queries are fast when result is stored in cache but is slow otherwise :(

Comment: @knagode,Hi can u answer if you have solved your above issue if its been fixed i m also getting same issue

Comment: @sunil since overall performance was good - we didn't do anything. Probably this leads to slower responses from time to time but we survived. I like what a_horse_with_no_name said .. if everything is fast enough, why would we do anything actually?

Comment: i've created a test database with just one row of two data, email & password, very simple.  with mocha testing, i'm seeing that it takes 3679ms to query, `SELECT * FROM users`.  It should be faster, right?  i'm seeing 0.98 index hr, 0.89 cache hr, with all else green in `heroku pg: diagnose`.  using the free tier.

Comment: @JosephK. I bet that your table is pretty huge and you are reading whole table. I think anything which is taking more than 100ms should be considered super slow query ...

Comment: @knagode no, it turned out that when i lowered my setTimeout to 5000, as shown in the `pg` suggested project structure, the query performance improved.  but i'm still talking about a fluctuation between 170ms to 700+ms.  my index hr is still 0.97 and cache hr is 0.89.  I have a question, at the top you stated that the hr's are lower than they should be, (>99%).  What does this mean?

Comment: @JosephK. If you want good performance cache HR should be as high as possible (because of low HR -> query speed varies). Since cache size is limited you want to have little data in query result - I am mentioning this because you are selecting all the data from users table - this will never scale well :)

Comment: @knagode i see. no, actually that's not going to be an issue for me because it's a test database with a table that has no data.  i'm using mocha to insert one row of data and then selecting it, then truncating the table as needed.  you also mentioned that you tuned your queries, how did you do that? comparatively, is it safe to assume that my queries are simple enough?

Comment: @JosephK. HR stats will probably change drastically on production table. I wouldn't care too much now - deploy and check e.g. New Relic to see which queries are slow. Fixing slow queries will most likely also improve DB HR.